# MS Teams bot no longer receives messages

Tags: microsoft-teams

After moving MS Teams bot to another server, it no longer replies to messages. It still successfully sends proactive messages on its own, however responding to messages no longer works. Messaging endpoint stayed the same (only IP changed)...
I watched for network activity when clicking a button in adaptive card (posted by bot) and error 502 is reported with `{"errorCode":1008,"message":"Invoke agent action failed with status code: BadGateway"}` returned. I'd appreciate any ideas how to sort this out... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the IP / URL of your bot changed you need to make sure to update the messaging endpoint in the bot definition. 
If you registered your bot in dev.botframework.com or azure there's a setting "messaging endpoint url" which you need to update and point to the new ip.

If just the IP behind your URL changed, it might be some caching/dns issue on MS Teams end. Did you try to reinstall the bot completely?

Comment: No, haven't reinstalled it, for new bot would probably get different IDs assigned for existing channels and users, so existing records data won't match new ID values... I'd like to avoid that if possible - kind of hoped there's a setting somewhere to have this sorted out.

Comment: As far as i know that doesn't happen. Its all based on the AppId and BotId you have in the manifest. You can easily see that, if you re-install an app its still the same bot window with the same conversation history. Its all based on these two Id's and as long as those don't change nothing will really change.So if you uninstall the app and use the same manifest as before, with the same ID's nothing will break but MS Teams might rescan your DNS entries.
Microsoft might cache the DNS for your URL and if you changed the IP it might just have stored the old IP somewhere. Its just a guess anyway.

Comment: Re-adding the same bot (after removing it first) didn't change anything - still doesn't work :/ ...

Answer (score 0):

After moving a bot to a new server we saw a 502 response and error code 1008.  Using the Teams web app in Chrome and watching the network traffic there was this request:

```
Request URL: https://teams.microsoft.com/api/chatsvc/amer/v1/agents/.../invokeRequest
Method: POST
Status Code: 502 Bad Gateway
```

The response body was:

```
{
    "errorCode": 1008,
    "message": "<BotError>Error when sending request to bot",
    "standardizedError": {
        "errorCode": 1008,
        "errorSubCode": 1,
        "errorDescription": "<BotError>Error when sending request to bot"
    }
}
```

The root cause was the new server was configured to only support TLS 1.3 and Microsoft Bot Services *only* support TLS 1.2, not 1.3 and not 1.1.